# OAUTH - Authorization URL "state" parameter is too long

Tags: actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using the Actions on Google OAUTH authorization flow. In the authorization URL, Google passes along a very long "state" parameter (500+ char) in the URL, yielding an error on the OAauth client/server ([Bunq](https://doc.bunq.com/#/oauth) to be precise).

I've seen more cases where this is an issue, also including [Amazon Skills](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/75718/oauth-state-parameter-too-long-can-it-be-shortened.html).

If I manually shorten the length of the 'state' parameter, the error disappears. But since Google is using the 'state' parameter as a ["bookmarking value"](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2), they do not allow for any alterations. There seems to be no way to resolve this issue on my side.

Here is an example of the Authorization URL that is generated by Actions on Google:

```
https://oauth.bunq.com/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com%2Fr%2F[MY PROJECT NUMBER]&client_id=[CLIENT ID]&response_type=code&state=[567 CHARACTERS]
```

Is there a way to shorten the state parameter, or to resolve this issue otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no specified limit on the characters forming a URL specified by the `Network Working Group` in [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html), the defacto convention used by many internet systems and browsers is up to [2k characters](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/924935). You should check with the internal codebase as well if there is any limit on the number of characters that can be included in a query string.